# Problem using a compare function inside of a class for sort()

Tags: c++

If you take a look at my function CardCompare inside of the class... It doesn't work! But, if I instead use the function where it is commented out in Hand.cpp, it works perfectly fine. Why is this?

Also, I am wondering if keeping the CardCompare function in my hand class makes less sense than keeping it in the Card class, if that is possible.

Hand.h

```
#ifndef HAND_H
#define HAND_H

#include <vector>
#include "Card.h"

class Hand {
    private:
        std::vector<Card> hand;
        int total;
        void CalculateTotal();
        bool CardCompare (Card i, Card j) {return ( i.RankInt() < j.RankInt() ); }//Does not work! :O
    public:
        Hand() {
            total = 0;
        }
        std::vector<Card> GetHand() const{ return hand;};
        void PrintHand();
        void AddToHand(Card c);

};



#endif
```

Hand.cpp

```
#include "Hand.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

void Hand::CalculateTotal() {
    for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++) {
            std::cout << hand[i].ToString() << std::endl;
    }
}

void Hand::PrintHand() {
    for (int i = 0; i < hand.size(); i++) {
        std::cout << hand[i].ToString() << std::endl;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;
}
/* If I place this right here, it works perfect.
bool CardCompare (Card i, Card j) {return ( i.RankInt() < j.RankInt() ); }
*/
void Hand::AddToHand(Card c) {
    hand.push_back(c);
    std::sort(hand.begin(),hand.end(),CardCompare);
}

int main() {
    Hand h;
    h.PrintHand();
    h.AddToHand(Card (2, ( Card::Suit )2 ) );
    h.PrintHand();
    h.AddToHand(Card (3, ( Card::Suit )3 ) );
    h.PrintHand();
    h.PrintHand();
    h.AddToHand(Card (1, ( Card::Suit )2 ) );
    h.PrintHand();
    h.AddToHand(Card (13, ( Card::Suit )3 ) );
    h.PrintHand();

    std::cout<< std::endl << std::endl;

    std::cout << h.GetHand()[0].ToString();
}
```

Card.h

```
#ifndef CARD_H
#define CARD_H

#include <string>

class Card {
public:
    enum Suit {
        SUIT_HEART,
        SUIT_DIAMOND,
        SUIT_CLUB,
        SUIT_SPADE
    };
    Card(int r = 1, Suit s = SUIT_HEART) : rank(r), suit(s)
    {}
    int GetRank() const { return rank; };
    Suit GetSuit() const { return suit; };
    std::string ToString() const;
    std::string SuitString() const;
    std::string RankString() const;
    int RankInt() const;


private:
    int rank;
    Suit suit;
    static const char * ranknames[];
    static const char * suitnames[];
    static const int     rankints[];
};
#endif
```

Card.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Card.h"
//#include <vector> //gtfo

const char * Card::ranknames[] = { "A", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "J", "Q", "K" };
const char * Card::suitnames[] = { "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spaces" };
const int    Card::rankints[]  = {11, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ,10 ,10, 10 };

std::string Card::ToString() const {
    std::string s = RankString();
    s.append(" of ");
    s.append(SuitString());
    return s;
}

std::string Card::SuitString() const {
    return suitnames[suit];
}

std::string Card::RankString() const {
    return ranknames[rank-1];
}

int Card::RankInt() const {
    return rankints[rank-1];
}
 /*
int main() {

    std::vector<Card> Deck;

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
        Deck.push_back(Card(i+1,(Card::Suit)((i+1)%4)));
        std::cout << Deck[i].ToString() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << std::endl << std::endl;
    std::random_shuffle( Deck.begin(), Deck.end() );

    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
            std::cout << Deck[i].ToString() << std::endl;
    }
}*/
```

Comment: Could you at least remove all the irrelevant code?

Comment: Sorry, I'll do that from now on.

Comment: Personal preference: Rather than casting numbers to `Card::Suit`s, you should have `static` members of `Card::Suit` called `Spades`, `Hearts`, `Diamonds`, and `Clubs`.

Comment: @Chris Lutz  Could you explain in more detail? I'm still a nub and am not sure what you mean.

Comment: @Colton - `class Card { public: class Suit { static const Suit Spades, Hearts, Diamonds, Clubs; ... }; ... }; const Card::Suit Card::Suit::Spades = 0, Card::Suit::Hearts = 1, Card::Suit::Clubs = 2, Card::Suit::Diamonds = 3;` Then you can add methods to the `Card::Suit` class, like `Card::Suit::isblack()` and such. Users of your class, instead of having to know that `(Card::Suit)0` is for spades, can just say `Card::Suit::Spades`.

Comment: So the Suit Class would have the value of the Suit which it actually is, as well as the 4 suits which can be used for comparions/casting, and the enumeration which I have already created?

Comment: @Colton - Basically. It can also have methods to test for the suit color, get a text representation of the suit name, etc. Using an `enum` is a very C way to do it (and as a predominantly C programmer, I won't tell you it's wrong) but when you have the extra stuff C++ puts at your disposal, it makes sense (to me) to use it.

Comment: @Chris  are you sure your code is correct? you have a static const Suit inside of a class named Suit, which you assign to an int.  I'm not exactly sure how this would work...

Comment: @Chris If you could use http://codepad.org to show me exactly what you mean, I would forever be in your debt! :O

Comment: @Colton - Sorry. I implemented it to see how it'd work, and I used a plain `int` to store the card type instead of an `enum`. Either one works. The way I did it was with a private ctor that takes an int, which is used to initialize the static `Card::Suit::*` members, and then a public ctor that takes a `const Card::Suit&` for general use. That way the users never have to (or can) know which numbers relate to which suits. (http://codepad.org/capzXTqQ)

Comment: Thanks a bunch, but now that you can't call a suit by an integer number, wouldn't that make setting up a deck of cards more difficult. Before it could be done with a simple nested for loop inside a for loop, now it seems I'll need to do something else. perhaps create a function that when passed an int returns a Suit :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to pass a pointer to a member function, so sort can't use it because it doesn't have `this` pointer. In your case you can just change the function to be `static`:

```
static bool CardCompare (Card i, Card j) {return ( i.RankInt() < j.RankInt() ); }
```

If you do need it be a non-static member function in the future, bind it with `boost::bind` or `std::bind` (for C++0x compiler):

```
std::sort(hand.begin(),hand.end(),bind(&Hand::CardCompare, this, _1, _2));
```

Comment: Sorry, a bit confused. So basically the sort() takes a pointer to a function, but since I didn't have it static, it could only be associated to an instantiation of an object? And since it is associated to a instance it would need the "this" pointer? Am I on the right track here?

Comment: @Colton: `sort` takes anything that it can call like this: `compare(a,b)`. It can be a function pointer or an object with `operator()` overloaded. It can't call a member function by `member(a,b)`, thus it doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

CardCompare() cannot be a member function if it is to be used in sort(). You can just overload operator< in the Card class to compare cards.

In card class, something like:

```
bool operator<(const Card& other) const {
    return RankInt() < other.RankInt();
}
```

Comment: With this solution, how would you call sort in my case?

    sort (hand.begin(), hand.end(), Card() ); ?

Comment: @Colton: `sort(hand.begin(), hand.end());` By default sort compares with `<`.

Answer (score 1):

The canonical solution is to overload `operator()` instead. This turns your class into a *functor*, and then it'll work out of the box with the standard library algorithms.

Just change

```
bool CardCompare (Card i, Card j) {return ( i.RankInt() < j.RankInt() ); }
```

to

```
bool operator()(Card i, Card j) {return ( i.RankInt() < j.RankInt() ); }
```

and then you can call sort like this:

```
std::sort(hand.begin(),hand.end(), Hand());
```

Normally, you'd put the comparison operator in a separate class though

Comment: So basicall by overloading the operator() function it allows my Hand class to be used with most of the STL algorithms as a container without having to make my own compare() functions (and whatever else I might have to do, still new to algorithms)  

And if I should put the comparison operator in a seperate class, then what class?

Comment: @Colton, @jalf I think that adopting this code exactly as suggested is not a good idea. jalf, you're creating Hand() (with a vector inside) each time want to sort. Either call it with `std::sort(..., *this);` or if you want to write operator() in Hand for comparison, it's better to write operator < instead.

Comment: @ybungalobill Oh okay, for example the paramater could determine whether its sorted in ascending or descending order right? Or whether to sort based on SUIT or Rank, etc.  Cool. Last thing, this struct would be kept in the Hand file?

Comment: @Colton: Oops, I've deleted my second comment because it almost repeated jalf's answer... Yes you can put it in Hand file, even as a private struct *inside* Hand class.

Comment: @Colton: it could, but it doesn't have to. I usually keep such comparer functors as entirely separate structs. But put it where you feel it makes sense.