# How to write a compare function inside a class when another function uses that to sort?

Tags: c++, stl, computational-geometry

I am trying to find the convex hull of some points in C++ in an object oriented way. So , for this I have defined a custom compare function. But the thing is I can't sort the values inside a class function. My problem is at line 46 which is line 3 at`find_convex_hull` function:
Here's my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define x first
#define y second
using namespace std;
typedef pair<int,int> ii;

class convex_hull{
    enum point_compare {greater,smaller,equal};
    vector<ii> points;
    vector<ii> convexHull;
    ii p0;
public:
    convex_hull(vector<ii> init)
    {
        sort(init.begin(),init.end());
        points = init;
        p0 = init[0];
    }
    int cross_product(ii p1,ii p2,ii p0)
    {
        return ((p1.x-p0.x)*(p2.y-p0.y))-((p1.y-p0.y)*(p2.x-p0.x));
    }
    point_compare compare(ii p1,ii p2,ii p0)
    {
        int d = cross_product(p1,p2,p0);
        if(d>0)
            return smaller;
        else if(d<0)
            return greater;
        else
            return equal;
    }
    bool sort_compare(ii p1,ii p2)
    {
        point_compare x = compare(p1,p2,p0);
        if(x == smaller)
            return true;
        else if(x == equal)
            return p1<p2;
        return false;
    }
    stack<ii> find_convex_hull()
    {
        vector<ii> polar_sorted = points;
        sort(polar_sorted.begin()+1,polar_sorted.end(),bind(&convex_hull::compare,this,placeholders::_1,placeholders::_2));
        stack<ii> res;
        res.push(p0);
        res.push(polar_sorted[1]);
        res.push(polar_sorted[2]);
        for(int i=3;i<polar_sorted.size();++i)
        {
            ii _y = res.top(); res.pop();
            ii _x = res.top();
            ii _z = polar_sorted[i];
            if(compare(_y,_z,_x) != greater)
                res.push(_y);
            res.push(_z);
        }
        return res;
    }
};

int main()
{

    vector<ii> points({{0, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {4, 4},
                       {0, 0}, {1, 2}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}});
    convex_hull A(points);
    stack<ii> res = A.find_convex_hull();
    while(!res.empty())
    {
        ii x = res.top();
        res.pop();
        cout<<x.x<<" "<<x.y<<endl;

    }

}
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288439/problem-using-a-compare-function-inside-of-a-class-for-sort) accepted solution , so at line 46 I used the bind function. But I am  getting a whole lot of awful errors. I don't want to make the compare function static cause then I have to change many thing to static. Is there any way of doing it?

Comment: your `point_compare compare(ii p1,ii p2,ii p0)` method takes three arguments whereas std::sort expects `binary predicate`. Did you mean to use `bind(&convex_hull::sort_compare` instead of `bind(&convex_hull::compare` ?

Comment: Yes , this was exactly the mistake. Thanks !!!

Comment: Also you can make `sort_compare` static (so you'll have to make `compare` and `cross_product` static as well, which is good because they don't rely on the `convex_hull` instance) and after that you can pass `sort_compare` directly to `sort` without using `bind`.

Comment: But then I have to make the p0 field static to which in turns is used in the constructor and depends on the instance.

Comment: What about using a lambda function for the compare if your compiler supports lambda functions?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here the BUG is in the calling function sort() . As Piotr S. mentioned in the comments ,I used `bind(&convex_hull::compare` which takes 3 arguments instead of `bind(&convex_hull::sort_compare` . which takes 2 arguments for the std::sort.