# Custom list.sort comparisons in C++

Tags: c++, list, sorting, stdlist

I have an std::list that I'm trying to sort based on some calculations.  Point2D is a struct with only int no, double x, and double y;

Here's the method that contains my list.sort code:

```
std::vector<Point2D> GrahamScan::getSortedPointSet(std::vector<Point2D> points) {
Point2D lowest = getLowestPoint(points);

std::list<Point2D> list;

for (int i = 0; i < (int)points.size(); i++) {
    list.push_back(points[i]);
}

list.sort(compare_points);

std::vector<Point2D> temp;
for (int i = 0; i < (int)list.size(); i++) {
    temp.push_back(list.front());
    list.pop_front();
}
return temp;
}
```

And here's the compare_points method I wrote:

```
bool GrahamScan::compare_points(const Point2D& a, const Point2D& b) {
if (a.x == b.x && a.y == b.y) {
    return false;
}

double thetaA = atan2((long)a.y - lowest.y, (long)a.x - lowest.x);
double thetaB = atan2((long)b.y - lowest.y, (long)b.x - lowest.x);

if (thetaA < thetaB) {
    return false;
}
else if (thetaA > thetaB) {
    return true;
}
else {
    double distanceA = sqrt((((long)lowest.x - a.x) * ((long)lowest.x - a.x)) +
        (((long)lowest.y - a.y) * ((long)lowest.y - a.y)));
    double distanceB = sqrt((((long)lowest.x - b.x) * ((long)lowest.x - b.x)) +
        (((long)lowest.y - b.y) * ((long)lowest.y - b.y)));

    if (distanceA < distanceB) {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
}
```

The error Visual Studio is spitting out at me is "GrahamScan::compare_points":non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member"

I don't have much experience in C++, but I'm trying to convert some Java code that uses a TreeSet to C++ and this is my attempt.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4288479/212870

Comment: Make the comparison function `static` and try again.  But let me warn you of the *strict-weak-order* requirement for the comparison function.  Your implementation is complex and it's hard to tell if it follows this requirement.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep `compare_points` in `GrahamScan` namespace you need to make it static:

```
static bool GrahamScan::compare_points
```

The reason the compiler complains is that `compare_points` is a member function. It needs a `GrahamScan` object to be applied on. Behind the curtains the real function signature of `compare_points` is something like `bool compare_points(GrahamScan *this, const Point2D& a, const Point2D& b)`. So either make it static or don't define it as a member function.

Once you make compare_points static, your lowest variable will no longer be accessible to it. Easier way to work around that is to make lowest also static:

```
class GrahamScan
{
    // declaration is inside class
    static Point2D lowest;
}

// definition is outside class
Point2D GrahamScan::lowest;
```

and use it like this:

```
std::vector<Point2D> GrahamScan::getSortedPointSet(std::vector<Point2D> points)
{
    GrahamScan::lowest = getLowestPoint(points);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Now I'm getting an "unresolved external symbol "private: static struct Point2D GrahamScan::lowest"" error.  I have tried declaring my Point2D variable lowest as static to no avail.

Comment: @awbasham Make sure you properly declare a static variable. If you make ```lowest``` static, then inside GrahamClass use ```static Point2D lowest```, put ```Point2D GrahamScan::lowest``` somewhere outside GrahamScan, and reference lowest by ```GrahamScan::lowest```.

Comment: What do you mean "put Point2D GrahamScan::lowest somewhere outside GrahamScan"?

Comment: @awbasham, I expanded my answer to illustrate.

Comment: LNK2005 "public: static struct Point2D GrahamScan::lowest" (?lowest@GrahamScan@@2UPoint2D@@A) already defined in ConsoleApplication2.obj error after implementing.

Comment: Or maybe the more useful error "one or more multiply defined symbols found"

Comment: @awbasham, make sure you have the ```Point2D GrahamScan::lowest;``` definition in only 1 cpp file, or if it's in the header, the header doesn't get included multiple times.